# PowerShell Scheduled task fails with error code: 0xFFFD0000 and 4294770688 if Run Hourly Every Day

Tags: scheduled-tasks

On a **Windows Server 2012 R2 Build 9600**, I have a Scheduled Task that **runs successfully on demand**.

I need it to **run every hour every day**.

**if I change it to "Run Hourly, Every Day"**, it **fails** with error codes: `0xFFFD0000` and `4294770688`, which stands for `"The field “Add arguments (optional)” contains an invalid file name"`.

This is a bit odd, because everything is ok on that field and **this only happens with that schedule combination**.

As example, **If I schedule it to run once a day at some time, it runs ok**.

Best Regards to All

Comment: Could you export the task to an .xml file (edit out any security info) and post the file?

Comment: This question is more suitable for [su], as it is not programming related. You can find more information about this site by taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had an action which called `powershell`. I had to quote the script file path in double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes (`'`).

So, this error code may have different reasons.

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work.

I had to set it up to "**Run Once, Every Hour, Indefinitely**"

Like: Run "**One time, Start at 0h00, Repeat Task Every 1 hour, Indefinitely**"

Also **do not use** the trigger option `Stop Task if it runs longer than` because it will throw back the `0xFFFD0000` error. Use it on the **Settings** instead.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error code and have fixed it by moving powershell script to a folder with no spaces in the file path.  In full, the Add arguments field is:

```
    -noprofile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File C:\users\myname\powershell_testing\my_powershell_script.ps1
```

Comment: If you have space characters in your path, quote it with double quotes (`"`).